# Python - TKinter - Editing Widgets

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, editing

I need a widget in TKinter to be a global widget, however, I need the text displayed in it to be different every time. I'm quite new with TKinter and haven't yet successfully managed to edit an option in a widget.

I assume it's something to do with widget.add_option() but the documentation is quite confusing to me and I can't figure out the command.

I specifically just need to edit the text = "" section.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
gm1_b_current_choice_label = Label(frame_gm1_b, text = "Current input is:\t %s"% str(save_game[6]))
```

I specifically need to update the save_game[6] (which is a list) in the widget creation, but I assume once the widget is created that's it. I could create the widget every time before I place it but this causes issues with destroying it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.config` method to change options on a Tkinter widget.

To demonstrate, consider this simple script:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Label

root = Tk()

label = Label(text="This is some text")
label.grid()

def click():
    label.config(text="This is different text")

Button(text="Change text", command=click).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

When the button is clicked, the label's text is changed.

Note that you could also do this:

```
label["text"] = "This is different text"
```

or this:

```
label.configure(text="This is different text")
```

All three solutions ultimately do the same thing, so you can pick whichever you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the `.configure(text = "new text")` method, as iCodez suggested.

Alternatively, try using a `StringVar` as the `text_variable parameter`:

```
my_text_var = StringVar(frame_gm1_b)
my_text_var.set("Current input is:\t %s"% str(save_game[6]))
gm1_b_current_choice_label = Label(frame_gm1_b, textvariable = my_text_var)
```

Then, you can change the text by directly altering `my_text_var`:

```
my_text_var.set("Some new text")
```

This can be linked to a button or another event-based widget, or however else you want to change the text.

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it. Will probably end up using it at some point in the future, for now, the simple     .config works